# Analytics implemented with Swift not working

Tags: ios, swift, analytics

I followed this tutorial using Google Analytics 3.10: http://flyingspheres.blogspot.com/2014/12/swift-google-analytics.html

I think that by doing all these steps I'd have some data showing in Real-Time overview in Google Analytics, but I don't. Everything is a 0.

Here's my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtExceptions = true
        GAI.sharedInstance().dispatchInterval = 20
        GAI.sharedInstance().logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose
        GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("UA-XXXXXXXX-X")

        //  GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtExceptions = true
        //GAI.sharedInstance().dispatchInterval = 20
      //  GAI.sharedInstance().logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose
       // GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("UA-60935611-2")

        var tracker:GAITracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
        tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value:"Home Screen")
        tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build())

        return true
    }
```

And here's my output in the console:

```
2015-03-21 20:09:04.748 WzoryStaleFizyczne[4148:217355] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 +[GAITrackerModel initialize] (GAITrackerModel.m:88): idfa class missing, won't collect idfa
2015-03-21 20:09:04.760 WzoryStaleFizyczne[4148:217427] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:497): Saved hit: {
    parameters =     {
        "&_crc" = 0;
        "&_u" = ".etnoK9L";
        "&_v" = "mi3.1.0";
        "&a" = 359875678;
        "&aid" = "com.krzysztofhadas.WzoryStaleFizyczne";
        "&an" = WzoryStaleFizyczne;
        "&av" = "1.0.1";
        "&cd" = "Home Screen";
        "&cid" = "e77fa8f7-e727-49af-9db9-93a5788d8621";
        "&ds" = app;
        "&sr" = 375x667;
        "&t" = screenview;
        "&tid" = "UA-XXXXXXXX-X";
        "&ul" = en;
        "&v" = 1;
        "&z" = 1148007052490650678;
        gaiVersion = "3.10";
    };
    timestamp = "2015-03-21 19:09:04 +0000";
}
2015-03-21 20:09:04.788 WzoryStaleFizyczne[4148:217355] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000002
2015-03-21 20:09:24.760 WzoryStaleFizyczne[4148:217427] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIRequestBuilder requestGetUrl:payload:] (GAIRequestBuilder.m:195): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
2015-03-21 20:09:24.761 WzoryStaleFizyczne[4148:217427] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatchWithCompletionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:612): Sending hit(s) GET: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?av=1.0.1&cid=e77fa8f7-e727-49af-9db9-93a5788d8621&tid=UA-60935611-2&cd=Home+Screen&a=359875678&t=screenview&aid=com.krzysztofhadas.WzoryStaleFizyczne&ul=en&_u=.etnoK9L&ds=app&sr=375x667&v=1&_crc=0&an=WzoryStaleFizyczne&_v=mi3.1.0&ht=1426964944756&qt=20003&z=1148007052490650678
2015-03-21 20:09:26.050 WzoryStaleFizyczne[4148:217355] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:208): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status -1
2015-03-21 20:09:26.051 WzoryStaleFizyczne[4148:217427] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:509): hit(s) Successfully deleted
2015-03-21 20:09:26.052 WzoryStaleFizyczne[4148:217427] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:219): 1 hit(s) sent
```

I imported all of the things and frameworks mentioned in the text in the link I sent.

Comment: This is not an answer but I am in the same boat.  Live data isn't coming through.  But I noticed that if I go to some of the other dashboards and filter using the current day, numbers to show up... eventually.

This is somewhat painful but I am going to keep looking

Comment: Happens to me  to. Setup goes Well, GAI logs Ok and Sending Stats, but the Dashboard is BLANK... Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to deal with this.  I used both the demo provided AND integrated it into my app.

Nothing.
0s.

Then I came in this morning to take a look.  It was working this morning.  So evidently there is a good bit of lag before this aspect of Google Analytics kicks in.

Comment: Ya, even though Google has some sections for real time analytics I haven't found it reliable. Best to wait 24 hours and view yesterdays analytics.